# Getting Element from ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>

Tags: java, android, listview, collections, hashmap

I am using nested collections of String and Hashmap of two strings into Arraylist and populating some data into listview using baseadapter. I want to fetch both strings from HashMap.

Code is here:

**1)**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> Menu = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>();
```

**2)**

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> mainMenu = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
```

**3)**

```
 HashMap<String,String> subMenu = new HashMap<String,String>();

                for (int k = 0; k < jsonsubmenu.length(); k++) {
                    // get all values from jsonsubmenu JSONArray..
                    String submenuname = jsonsubmenu.optString(k);
                    String price = jsonpeicemenu.optString(k);

                    subMenu.put(submenuname, price);


                }

                mainMenu.put(mainmenu, subMenu);

                Menu.add(mainMenu);
```

**4)**

```
MenuAdapter menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(
                        RestaurantDetails.this.getParent(), Menu);

                list.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
```

Above code pieces shows the meaning full flow of usage of collection. I am using below statements for picking the data from selected positions but these statements are not worth. Please suggest me how to fetch data at seleted position.

```
Stringn menu = Menu.get(position).get(TAG_MENUNAME);
String cost = Menu.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE);
```

Comment: Small comment: in mainMenu.put(mainmenu,subMenu) - what is the String mainmenu, should it not be the label for subMenu.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
String cost = Menu.get(position).get(TAG_MENUNAME).get(TAG_SUBMENU);
```

Comment: You'll want to enclose that in a try{...}catch(NullPointerException e){...} as the first map might return null.

Comment: Depends on if the programmer controls the input or not. Catching NullPointerException are not the recommended way to go.

Comment: What do you get? I just came up with `TAG_SUBMENU`. You'll need to replace that with the actual submenu name. Btw. I don't think you need to wrap the menus in an ArrayList. Use LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> instead to get predictive iteration order.